# Should we use discrete or continuous variable formula to solve the below question?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

[image: Question]

I have used the formula of Discrete variable. It has specified in the question "...over a period of time." so I am confused if it should be continuous variable formula?

Comment: You are looking at probability of commercials tho, and thats a discrete value

Comment: Unless you want to start chopping up parts of the unfortunate commercials that get stuck in the boundaries of the time period, it should be discrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Addressing only the parts about the CDF:* I suggest you make a table with three columns headed $x$, PDF or $f_X(x),$ and CDF or $F_X(x),$ and rows
for $x = 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.$ Then a plot of the CDF against x, will look somewhat
like the following.

[image]

The heavy dots are from your table. Strictly speaking, only the horzontal
line segments are part of the CDF; the vertical line segments are often
added (sometimes as dotted lines), to make the graph easier to follow.

*Trying to clear up possible points of confusion:*

- While the CDF of a random variable is defined
  for all values of $x$ on the real line, we usually plot the CDF in an
  interval of $x$'s where the random variable $X$ has positive probability.
- The values taken by the CDF are always in the interval $[0,1].$ For your random variable $X,$  we have $F_X(-3) = F_X(4) = F_X(4.999) = 0,\,
  F_X(5) = F_X(5.5) =  0.2,$ and $F_X(9) = F_X(27) = 1.$
- This is the CDF of a *discrete* random variable. All increases as one
  moves from left to right are 'jumps'; the CDF is a 'pure jump function'.
- The CDF of a *continuous* random variable has no jumps at all.

In part (b),

$$P(X < 8) = P(X \le 7) =F_X(7)= P(X = 5) + P(X = 6) + P(X = 7),$$
where $F_X$ is the CDF of $X.$ Also,

$$P(6 < X < 8) = P(X = 7)  = F_X(7) - F_X(6).$$

This is the height of the vertical line segment on the graph above $X=7.$